# curly brace notation calculus

Tags: notation

find {x:dv/dx = 0}
I had to guess what this notation meant i could not find a reference to it. Does anyone have an explanation or reference. My interpretation is, find the value(s) of x that satisfy dv/dx = 0

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. This is set notation (can look up some basic "set theory"). Assuming $v$ is a previously defined function, the set $\{x~:~dv/dx = 0\}$ can be described as "the set of all points $x$ (probably in the domain of $v$) where $dv/dx = 0$.

Comment: Ah yes setbuilder notation, more use to | than : . Yes dv/dx is a function. Thanks.